# How to trigger default Bootstrap 4 form validation error message from custom external script

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, forms, validation

In our contact form, I'm trying to only allow submissions from email addresses from the United States, since we can only do business in that one country. How can I trigger the default error message when a form submit attempt is made, so that "invalid" message appears the same way it appears for the first name and last name fields?

In the code below, for the sake of example, I'm allowing only 'com', 'edu', 'gov', 'net', 'org'. The goal is to trigger a message whenever an email address other than those above is entered into the email field.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(function() {
    $("#testform").submit(function() {
      str = $('input[name=emailAddress]').val();
      str = str.split('@').slice(0);
      str = str[1].split('.').slice(0);

      var allowedDomains = ['com', 'edu', 'gov', 'net', 'org'];

      alert("str = " + str[1]);

      if ($.inArray(str[1], allowedDomains) !== -1) {
        alert(str + ' is allowed');

      } else {
        alert('not allowed');
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
        $('#emailAddress').addClass('invalid');
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/assets/js/vendor/holder.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/assets/js/vendor/popper.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <form action="" method="post" target="" class="needs-validation" role="form" id="testform">
    <fieldset>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="firstName" class="col-form-label">Customer first name:
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="firstName" id="firstName" required aria-required="true">
    </label>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="lastName" class="col-form-label">Customer last name:
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="lastName" id="lastName" required aria-required="true">
    </label>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="emailAddress" class="col-form-label">Customer email address:
    <input type="email" class="form-control" name="emailAddress" id="emailAddress" required placeholder="Enter valid email" aria-required="true">
    </label>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: you can write onblur function on input textbox, so that whenever user leave textbox that function will execute and show error if it is invalid

Comment: The problem I'm having is how do I trigger and display the error message? The function I've written is preventing invalid form submissions. It's just not showing the message to alert users to enter a valid email address.

Comment: You should display error message in some container

Comment: Here whatever error messages are creating that are based on basic html validations
What you are writing html validates  do not have such rule that's why email validation error message is not showing

Comment: I'd like to create an error message for that 'email' field that has the same look and feel as the validation error messages for 'first name' and 'last name'.